# Checking string and handling invalid date

Tags: java, datetime

When I come across invalid dates, i.e. `2018-02-31, 2018-11-31`, I want my code to convert it to last day of that month.

I am not sure how to check for value within the passed string.

Here is my code so far:

```
/**
     * If date comes back as invalid, i.e. 2018-11-31
     * convert it to have last day of given month.
     *  
     * @param nextFieldTypeDate
     * @return
     */
    public static LocalDate resolveInvalidDate(String nextFieldTypeDate) {
        LocalDate convertedDate = null;
        try {
            convertedDate = LocalDate.parse(nextFieldTypeDate);
        } catch(DateTimeException dte) {
            //convertedDate = convert date to have last day of the month
            DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM");
            String yearMonthString = nextFieldTypeDate.subSequence(0, 7).toString();
            YearMonth ym = YearMonth.parse(yearMonthString, fmt);
            convertedDate = ym.atEndOfMonth();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
            throw new ConversionException("Unable to convert nextFieldTypeDate.", e);
        }
        return convertedDate;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `parseUnresolved` method of a `DatetimeFormatter` parses without trying to make sense of the parsed values. It therefore accepts an invalid date and allows you to inspect the parsed values before you try to make a `LocalDate` out of them.

```
public static LocalDate resolveInvalidDate(String nextFieldTypeDate) {
    ParsePosition position = new ParsePosition(0);
    TemporalAccessor parsed = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE
            .parseUnresolved(nextFieldTypeDate, position);
    if (position.getIndex() < nextFieldTypeDate.length()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not parse entire string");
    }
    YearMonth ym = YearMonth.from(parsed);
    int lastDayOfMonth = ym.lengthOfMonth();
    int parsedDayOfMOnth = parsed.get(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    if (parsedDayOfMOnth > lastDayOfMonth) { // invalid, must be adjusted to lasst day of month
        return ym.atEndOfMonth();
    } else {
        return ym.atDay(parsedDayOfMOnth);
    }
}
```

Let’s try this version of your method out:

```
    System.out.println(resolveInvalidDate("2018-02-31"));
    System.out.println(resolveInvalidDate("2018-02-27"));
```

Output is:

> ```
> 2018-02-28
> 2018-02-27
> ```

So February 31 was invalid and has been adjusted into February 28, which in 2018 was the last day of that month. February 27 is valid and is returned as is.

**Edit:** For a related purpose one might have considered the much easier `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE.withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.LENIENT).parse(nextFieldTypeDate, LocalDate::from)`. This, however, turns `2018-02-31` into `2018-03-03`, which I understand is not what you want.

Comment: when I pass 2018-14-25, it bombs on YearMonth ym = YearMonth.from(parsed);

Comment: It does. Do you want the 14 adjusted to 12? You may want to add that to your question.

Comment: No. I placed it in try-catch and am throwing exception when is invalid month

Answer (score 1):

Not the cleanest solution but this should work:

```
public static LocalDate resolveInvalidDate(String nextFieldTypeDate) {
        LocalDate convertedDate = null;
        try {
            convertedDate = LocalDate.parse(nextFieldTypeDate);
        } catch(DateTimeException dte) {
            //convertedDate = convert date to have last day of the month
            Integer[] constituents = Arrays.stream(nextFieldTypeDate.split("-"))
                                           .map(constituentString -> Integer.valueOf(constituentString))
                                           .toArray(Integer::new);
            LocalDate defaultDate = LocalDate.of(constituents[0], constituents[1], 1);
            LocalDate convertedDate = LocalDate.of(defaultDate.getYear(), defaultDate.getMonth(), defaultDate.lengthOfMonth());
        } catch(Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
            throw new ConversionException("Unable to convert nextFieldTypeDate.", e);
        }
        return convertedDate;
    }
```